# When I try to use styled properties of material UI its give a type error how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Error:

> TypeScript error in D:/Projects/React
> Projects/almond-boats/src/App.tsx(32,8): Type '{ children: string; }'
> is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<number,
> "className" | "theme">': toFixed, toExponential, toPrecision  TS2739

my code as follows:

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/styles";

const MyButton = styled(Button)({
  background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
  color: "white",
  height: 48,
  padding: "0 30px",
});

const App = () => {
  return <MyButton> hey there</MyButton>;
};

export default App;
```

how to solve this...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce on both styled-component and emotion style engines. Can you put all of your code and the package.json here?

Comment: your code works fine, this could be a TS config issue https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-ts-styled-5j9vi?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: It solved itself after a time when I close ide and its work fine... 
It's crazy things...